# SQL Average Calculation based on conditions of other columns

Tags: sql, where-clause

How do I output the average for one column based on conditions from other columns? For example, this is what I did:

```
SELECT  
    AVG(TestScores WHERE ID = 1 AND Date_On BETWEEN '2017-04-08' AND '2017-04-12' AND Code = '87A')    
FROM
    Table_Name
```

My desired goal is to obtain the average of the `TestScores` column when the `ID` of the `row = 1` and when the date falls between my specified interval. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you tell us which DBMS your using  and Table structure ?

Comment: It's possible, but your code does not represent valid sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Sql Server, then below is what you are looking for (I think):

```
SELECT 
    AVG(TestScores)   
FROM
    Table_Name
WHERE ID = 1 
    AND Date_On BETWEEN '2017-04-08' AND '2017-04-12' 
    AND Code = '87A'
```

> EDIT, as per comments underneath:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    AVG(TestScores)   
FROM
    Table_Name
WHERE 
    Date_On BETWEEN '2017-04-08' AND '2017-04-12' 
    AND Code = '87A'
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: This would work in many DBMS, not only SQL Server. Though in an ANSI compliant DBMS we'd use date literals (`date '2017-04-08'`) instead of relying on implicit conversions of string literals (`'2017-04-08'`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thnx

Comment: @PawelCz Is it possible to do this for multiple ID numbers at once? So I want the average for when ID = 1 and 2. I tried adding the ID number but it gave me an aggregate average rather than the average for 1 and then for 2

Comment: Got it working now! Just had to use a Group By at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is query : -

```
SELECT  AVG(TestScores)    
FROM  Table_Name 
WHERE ID = 1 AND
Date_On BETWEEN '2017-04-08' AND '2017-04-12' AND Code = '87A'
```